# How to ignore invalid input when reading file?

Tags: c++, file, c++11, vector, input

Working on an exercise that asks to find sum of numbers in file while ignoring invalid input, i.e. "bears: 17 elephants 9 end" would output 26. Right now when reading the file the input terminates as soon as it encounters an error, and I've been trying to find how to get around that. I'm sure the problem is at the ist.fail() part at read_file.

```
void read_file(string iname, vector<int>& result) {
  ifstream ist {iname}; // ist reads from the file named iname
  if (!ist) error("can't open input file ",iname);

  for (int temp; ist >> temp; ) 
    result.push_back(temp);
  
  if (ist.fail()) {
    ist.clear(ios_base::failbit);
  }
}

void write_file(string& oname, string& input1, const vector<int>& result) {
  ofstream ost {oname}; // ost writes to a file named oname
  if (!ost) error("can't open output file ",oname);

  double sum = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<result.size(); ++i)
    sum += result[i];
  ost << sum;
}

int main()
{ 
  string input = "a.txt";
  string output = "b.txt";
  vector<int> result;

  read_file(input, result);
  write_file(output, input, result);
}
```

Comment: Your suspicions were true: "the problem is at the ist.fail() part at read_file", indeed. Because, even if `ist` in failed state, and this part of the code clears it, it makes no difference whatsoever, since the code returns from the function anyway, destroying the input stream, and the open file. Can you explain your reasoning for explicitly clearing the input stream state before destroying the input stream completely, in all cases, and thus accomplishing absolutely nothing, by that?

Comment: Actually modified ist.fail() slightly so that following it is ist.clear() and ist.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'). So I cleared the error state and then ignored the data in the stream. Still same result though.

Comment: Why would you expect any different result? The code still returns from the function, anyway. You are forgetting The Golden Rule Of Computer Programming: "your computer always does exactly what you tell it to do instead of what you want it to do". You told your computer: after doing all of that, clearing the state, ignoring input, whatever: return from the function and stop reading from the file. Your computer is simply following your instructions. If you want your computer to do something else, you have to tell your computer exactly what your computer should do.

Answer (score 0):

Read each space-separated token into a string, attempt to convert it to an integer. If it fails, skip the token, otherwise insert it into the vector:

```c++
#include <sstream>

void read_file(string iname, vector<int>& result) {
  ifstream ist{iname};  // ist reads from the file named iname
  if (!ist) error("can't open input file ", iname);

  istringstream iss;
  for (string token; ist >> token; iss.clear()) {
    iss.str(token);
    int val;
    if (iss >> val) {
      result.push_back(val);
    }
  }
}
```